# How to convert char* to std::vector?

Tags: c++

I have a char* variable:

```
// char* buffer;
// ...
fread (buffer, 1, lSize, pFile);
// ...
```

How can I convert it to std::vector? Casting will get me an error.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Why not use a `std::vector` to begin with:

```
std::vector<char> buffer(lSize);
std::fread(&buffer[0], 1, buffer.size(), pFile);
```

Comment: ...because he has a `char *`

Answer (score 105):

```
std::vector<char> data(buffer, buffer + size);
```

James McNellis answer is better if you can do it like that.

Comment: Even though James' answer encourages better code, this is the correct answer to the question. Sometimes you simply have a char * to begin with.

Comment: Does this copy the data inside the buffer or just wrap it ?

Comment: @RayHulha it copies the data

Answer (score 14):

You can't cast between a char* and a vector; pointer casting causes the result to have the exact same bytes as the input, so it's generally a bad idea unless you're doing low-level bit manipulation.

Assuming you wanted to build a vector of chars, you can create a new vector object of type `std::vector<char>` (note that you need to supply the type of the vector's elements), and initialise it from the array by passing the begin and end pointers to the constructor:

```
std::vector<char> vec(buffer, buffer+lSize);
```

Note that the second argument is an "end pointer", very common in C++. Importantly, it is a pointer to the character *after* the end of the buffer, not the last character in the buffer. In other words, the start is inclusive but the end is exclusive.

Another possibility (since you're dealing with chars) is to use a `std::string` instead. This may or may not be what you want (depending on whether you're thinking about the char* as a string or an array of bytes). You can construct it in the same way:

```
std::string str(buffer, buffer+lSize);
```

or with a different constructor, taking the size as the second argument:

```
std::string str(buffer, lSize);
```