# convert unsigned char* into std::vector<uint8_t>

Tags: c++

Hey I am trying to convert unsigned char* into std::vector<uint8_t> and here's what I have already tried.

```
uint64_t something(unsigned char* raw1)
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> raw_image;
    for (auto b : raw1) {
        raw_image.push_back(b);
    }
}
```

I could not get it to work, any more help will be appreciated!!

Comment: You do need to know the size of the pointed to array (`raw1`). Which you don't have in this code snippet

Comment: the size is 893

Comment: duplicates: [C++ how to convert char array to vector of bytes (vector<byte>)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52629526/995714), [Cast char* to std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7619806/995714), [How to convert char* to std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4272445/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert unsigned char\[\] to std::vector<unsigned char>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951537/how-to-convert-unsigned-char-to-stdvectorunsigned-char)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you know the size, you can easily use the correct `std::vector` [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) instead of your loop:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> raw_image(raw1, raw1 + raw1_size);
```

In this case the above invokes the iterator constructor overload.

With that said, remember that this creates a *copy* of the data, it's not a "view" of the data pointed to by `raw1`. For that you could use the C++20 [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) class, if available.